# Error when parsing Json multiple times

Tags: ios, json, swift, parsing

I am running into an error when parsing JSON data multiple times. The bit of code below is in a function that gets called multiple times. The function works and loads data if it is called once, but begins to fail randomly when I call it multiple times in a row.

I get an error:

> Thread 4: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

right on the `for(key, _) in jsonData!{` line.

Any idea how I can improve the reliability of this?

```
    struct financialData {
    var date: NSDate
    var open: String
    var high: String
    var low: String
    var close: String
    var volume: String

  }

func comparisonData(symbol:String){
    var comparisonDataArray = [financialData]()
    let apiKey: String = "SAMPLEAPIKEY"
    let timeLength: String = "TIME_SERIES_DAILY"
    let url = URL(string: "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=\ 
    (timeLength)&symbol=\(symbol)&outputsize=compact&apikey=\(apiKey)")!

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response,
        error) in
        if error != nil {
            print ("ERROR")
        } else {
            if let content = data {
                do {
                    let myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with:
                        content, options: 
                    JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers)
                        as AnyObject

                let jsonData = myJson["Time Series (Daily)"] as? [String:Any]

                    // loop that goes through days until todays date
                    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
                    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

                    for(key, _) in jsonData!{
                       let date = key as String

                        if let cell = jsonData![date] as? NSDictionary {

                           let date = dateFormatter.date(from: date)! as NSDate
                           let open = cell["1. open"] as! String
                           let high = cell["2. high"] as! String
                           let low = cell["3. low"] as! String
                           let close = cell["4. close"] as! String
                           let volume = cell["5. volume"] as! String
                           let dataCell = financialData(date: date, open: open,
                                                         high: high, low: low, 
                        close: close, volume: volume)
                            comparisonDataArray.append(dataCell)
                        }
                    }
                    self.sortData()
                    self.arrayOfArrays.append(comparisonDataArray)
                }  catch  {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Here is the Data i am attempting to parse and add to an array using a struct

```
    "Time Series (Daily)" =     {
    "2018-02-26" =         {
        "1. open" = "176.3500";
        "2. high" = "179.3900";
        "3. low" = "176.2100";
        "4. close" = "178.9700";
        "5. volume" = 36886432;
    };
    "2018-02-27" =         {
        "1. open" = "179.1000";
        "2. high" = "180.4800";
        "3. low" = "178.1600";
        "4. close" = "178.3900";
        "5. volume" = 38685165;
    };
    "2018-02-28" =         {
        "1. open" = "179.2600";
        "2. high" = "180.6150";
        "3. low" = "178.0500";
        "4. close" = "178.1200";
        "5. volume" = 33604574;
    };
```

Comment: Don't use `!`. Properly unwrap optionals, especially when dealing with JSON.

Comment: Why **JSONSerialization** when there is **JSONDecoder**  , **ObjectMapper**  and **SwiftyJSON**

Comment: It seems that `jsonData` is nil. What is `myJson`?  avoid `NSDictionary`, and NSStuff in general when there is a Swift Equivalent (Dictionary).

Comment: please post the full json  that you expect

Comment: how would i adapt this to use JSONDecoder, ObjectMapper and SwiftyJson?

Comment: Added the Json Data i am expecting as well as the struct i am attempting to use

Comment: Your _the Data_ is in plist-like format (not JSON) and may be missing some important parts. What do you get with putting `print(String(data: contents, encoding: .utf8)!)` before the line `do {` ?

Comment: I suggest adding some basic error handling to check if you have gotten a complete response from the server. "...that gets called multiple times", it might be if you call this service to often it will refuse to return price data.